# JQuery Ajax fail with response of parse error when using ASP.NET identity in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm currently using JQuery Ajax to send some data to AccountController

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Account/Register',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    }
});
```

**Account Contrller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Register(string data)
{
    JObject json = JObject.Parse(data);

    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = json["login"], Email = json["login"] };
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, json["password"]);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

        return Json(new { success = true, html = "", message = "111" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return Json(new { success = false, html = "", message = "222" }); ;
}
```

And I get the following response object in ajax error section:
[image]

I think ajax request was sent to the back end. But I tried to set break points on `Register` function, the program doesn't trigger any break point. And I can't understand where the response object came from.

Does anyone know whats happening here?

------------------ Edit -----------------------------------------------------------

Great thanks to @freedomn-m, I found something interesting.
[image]

Here the response header gives 401 status, so I guess ajax fails because I miss some security token here. But does anyone know what token I missed?

Comment: It looks like the POST was ok, but the response was not valid JSON.   Check the *network tab* to see the complete details for the POST.  Alternatively (at least temporarily) remove the `dataType: "json"` so you can see what's being returned in the `console.log`

Comment: Thank you @freedomn-m, I found some interesting result. Would you like to have a look?

Comment: Strange that you're getting a 200(success) status, but a 401(unauthorised) inside it.  Can you change your Register function so that it's a one liner: `return Json(new { success=true });`?

Comment: Yeah I tried but still the same result. The response header contains a ```x-responsed-json``` field saying ```{"status":401,"headers":{"location":"https:\/\/localhost:44354\/Account\/Login?ReturnUrl=/Account/Register"}}```. Its weird that the url here points to the login page with return url of register.

Comment: In controller code you are using ````data```` everywhere instead of ````json```` variable you parsed in first line. Was that your intention?

Comment: @cly Oh that's some typo issue and I have changed it to json.

Comment: So still having the same problem? How your POSTed data look like?

Comment: @ cly I found the issue. That's nothing related to the code I put here. It is because the controller is marked as authorized but I didn't allow anonymity when register.